# The "Authorization" header is not sent in OPTIONS call by the browser

Tags: javascript, cors

I have a very simple HTTP call:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5500/v1/homes/', {
  method: "GET", 
  mode: "cors", 
  credentials: "same-origin", 
  headers: {
     Authorization: "TEST"
  }})
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

But when I look into the "Networks" tab of Google Chrome DevTools, the OPTIONS request does not have the "Authorization" header in it. This causes the server to replies with 401 Unauthorized.

The browser's curl equivalent of the request:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/v1/homes/' \
-X OPTIONS -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' \
-H 'Origin: http://localhost:8100'
-H 'Referer: http://localhost:8100/'
-H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36'
-H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization'
--compressed
```

Am I doing something wrong in the client side or is it quite common that browsers do not send the Authorization header in OPTIONS request, and therefore, I need to change the server in a way to response to OPTIONS call without requiring Authorization header?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> is it quite common that browsers do not send the Authorization header in OPTIONS request

More than common. It is required by [the CORS spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) which says "*for a cross-origin request with preflight … make a preflight request … Exclude user credentials*".

> I need to change the server in a way to response to OPTIONS call without requiring Authorization header?

Yes

Answer (score 5):

An `Options` call is requested by the client, in your case Chrome browser implicitly before the actual `GET` call.

> From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS)
>
> The HTTP OPTIONS method is used to describe the communication options
>   for the target resource. The client can specify a URL for the OPTIONS
>   method, or an asterisk (*) to refer to the entire server.

On the server side, you'll have to intercept this Options request and respond back with a HTTP Status code of 200 and a `Allow` header indicating the operations that are permitted on this resource. eg: `Allow: HEAD,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS`

The browser on receiving these details will then proceed with the `Get` call.

Comment: While these are a bunch of facts about OPTIONS request, you haven't answered the question.

Comment: No, it isn't. It's a lightweight explanation about what the response to a preflight needs to contain. It makes no mention of the missing Authorization header that the question is asking about.