# API Request with Header lands as OPTIONS on APIGEE and returns CORS when sent as POST from Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, apigee, apigee-baas

I have an API Proxy configured on APIGEE which I am using in my React App with Axios.

The problem is when I enable the OAuth2.0 Policy in the proxy the API lands as OPTION and returns a CORS Error, while I send it as a POST.

The POST request lands successfully and also returns the intended response when I disable the OAuth Policy.

I also tried using the CORS policy in both the Proxy and Target Endpoint before and after the OAuth Policy but that to returns a CORS error.

I have read about the Options Preflight and how to handle it via APIGEE but that bypasses the Authorization as well and returns a null route which would render that request useless.

I'd really apricate some help on this. TIA

Comment: Preflight `OPTIONS` requests should be excluded from any authentication / authorisation checks; they will not be made with any `Authorization` headers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The "Authorization" header is not sent in OPTIONS call by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52072001/the-authorization-header-is-not-sent-in-options-call-by-the-browser)

Comment: Once debug this in firefox and see what is the whole CORS error in Network Tab

Answer (score 0):

With preflight requests you are not expected to route this to a backend (no route). I am not sure which version of Apigee you are using but on X they now have a cors policy that you can generate preflight requests (). HOwever, if on other versions you can look at this approach [cors policy](https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/develop/adding-cors-support-api-proxy)